# React Native how to open react-native-dropdown-picker programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Is there a way to programmatically open picker's dropdown list of items?
How can i get the value(string in this case) of the selected item for some other use?
I'm using react-native-dropdown-picker library

At first i have this:
[image]

Then when i click on it, i have this:
[image]

I want to open this picker programmatically somehow to skip this second step, so that picker opens up automatically and i get this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the `open` [Prop](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/usage#open) for the `DropDownPicker`.

In this example, the DropDownPicker will open when the component gets mounted.

```
function DropDown() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'apple'},
    {label: 'Banana', value: 'banana'},
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(true); // this will trigger the dropdown visibility
  }, []);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
      setOpen={setOpen}
    />
  );
}
```